# Laravel передать json в javascript

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

Как правильно отправить json из laravel, а потом принять его в js? Как я понимаю,
этот код отправляет json на страницу index, но как в js принять этот json?

```
$even = DB::table('Table')->select('Name', 'Location')->get();
$jeven = json_encode($even);
$data = ['Title'=>'заголовок', 'even'=>$jeven];
return view('index', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере возвращайте

```
return Response::json($data);
```

В js обработайте ответ в случае успешного выполнения запроса или в случае ошибки

```
    success: function(data){
         out = JSON.parse(data);
         title = out.title;
         // обрабатываем успешное выполнение запроса
    },
    error: function() {
        // выводим инфу об ошибке
    }
```

Comment: А если мне нужно в контроллере возвращать все так $data = ['Title'=>'заголовок', 'even'=>$jeven];
return view('index', $data);

Comment: @Xenvert Зачем вам вью отдавать ajax запросом? Проверяйте в контроллере, если ajax запрос `if (Request::ajax())`, то отдавайте json объект, если нет, то отдавайте вьюху

Comment: Просто эта функция ajaxa засунута в onload() :) получается мне нужно возвращать и представление, и json

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас laravel 5 лучшим решением вернуть json будет отправить новый JsonResponse объект.
`return new Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse($data);`

Answer (score 0):

То как вы делаете – рабочий вариант. Во View будут доступны переменные `$Title` и `$even`.

Остаётся во вывести json-строку и назначить JS-переменной:

```
var data;
try {
  data = <?php echo $even; ?>;
} catch(e) {
  // в случае ошибки можно назначить default
  data = []; 
};
```